# Using profiles in liquibase

Tags: parameter-passing, liquibase

I am using Liquibase and would like to execute the same script in two different variants (production and tests):

```
<changeSet author="..." id="...">   
    <insert tableName="...">
            <column name="ACTIVE" value="${isActive}" />
    </insert>
</changeset>
```

Currently, I use a property to steer this in two files:

```
<!--File1: For production --> 
<property name="isActive" value="true"/>

<!--File2: For tests--> 
<property name="isActive" value="false"/>
```

Is there a way to use something like a profile (as in Maven) or use command line arguments in Liquibase? I would like to avoid the handling of two different files, one for the production and one for the test systems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may specify `context` parameter for property or changeSet itself:

```
<property name="isActive" value="true" context="prod"/>
<property name="isActive" value="false" context="test"/>
```

Then pass the context parameter to liquibase in some way:

```
mvn liquibase:migrate -Dliquibase.contexts=prod
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the post is old but I found a cleaner way using maven profiles directly.
(Since you were asking to use maven profiles).
You can use the liquibase.properties file and use the "parameter" properties of liquibase to access the variable from your changelog.
Lets say you use the maven profile "prod", then you include the following to the liquibase-prod.properties:

```
parameter.isActive=true
```

Now you can simply call:

```
mvn -Pprod liquibase:update
```

Then it will replace automatically the ${isActive} variable that you put into your changelog:

```
<property name="isActive" value="${isActive}"></property>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using cmd or terminal then use :

```
--contexts=prod
```

Answer (score 1):

*For me this setting of profiles in pom.xml was inspiring:*

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>db-diff</id>
        <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                  ...some profile db-diff settings like url, username password...
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>db-update</id>
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  ...some profile db-update settings like url, username, password...
  </profile>
```

*using for example profile db-update for update:*

```
mvn liquibase:update -Pdb-update
```